# Scrapy: Access CrawlSpider url list

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am writing a script that will inventory all site urls.

I am using CrawlSpider w/ rules handler to process scraped url's. Specifically, "filter_links" checks a table for existing url. If not found, writes new entry.

```
    rules = [
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(unique=True), follow=True, callback="parse_item", process_links="filter_links")
]
```

I sense this is just a poor mans 'reinventing the wheel' where a better method surely exists.

Is there a better way to dump the list of url's scrapy found vs. trying to parse this from response? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making use of `process_links` the way it is intended to be used. I see no drawbacks to that. But if you want to get rid of this additional `filter_links` method, then you can include the url table lookup and update logic in your `parse_item` method. You can access the current url in `parse_item` as `response.url`